# Phonegap Android Ajax Stopped Working

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova, phonegap-build

I am updated phonegap build 6.3.4 (Cordova 6.4.0). Until now all ajax calls to server was working fine. It suddenly stopped.

I faced a similar situation with iOS build and it turned to be a a new addition to the Content-Security-Policy. I am wondering if anything has been added for Android?

Finally, is there a proper information on the content-security tags to be added?

plugins

```
cordova-plugins-whitelist
```

config.xml

```
    <access origin="http://*" />
    <access origin="https://*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
```

index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src * 'self' data:; default-src * 'self' gap: wss: ws: ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';">
```

Comment: try using  whitelist plugin `https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/`  and allow your domain

Comment: `<allow-navigation href="http://example.com/*" />` or `<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />`

Comment: Hi, I already have cordova-plugin-whitelist .. but I havent added all domains in the allow-navigation

Comment: have you tried adding navigation?is it working for you?

Comment: sorry if I wasnt clear earlier. I have installed the cordova-plugin-whitelist already. And this tag exists in my config <allow-navigation href="http://*.mydomain.com" /> <allow-navigation href="https://*.mydomain.com" />

This was working until the last build (about a week back)

Comment: if still wont work add this following in your html file `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"/>`

Answer (score 0):

When you have done everything  and still ajax isnt working, its time to look at your SSL. My aha moment was when app worked in debug but not in release mode.

That led to this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021743/cordova-release-behaves-differently-to-debug-regarding-ssl). Due to wrong SSL implementation Android doesnt detect the certificates.

In Debug mode, android overrides the SSL issues (so it worked). In Release mode it failed silently and caused the problem.

I updated the root certificate / intermediate certificate / site certificates to resolve it