# Cordova App won't do SSL in Release Build

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic App, which needs to connect to a Server with SSL (It's a HTTPS URL). When I run `cordova build` and an unsigned Debug APK gets created everything works fine. Once I run `cordova build --release` and sign the App as demonstrated in the Docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html the request gets cancelled with no Error Message. I found out that this is due a missing SSL-certificate, which Android automatically cancels.

How can I solve this? Just create a Certificate, add it to my Keystore and then?

Or is there something else going wrong?

Comment: Do you have the allow-intent https in your config?

Comment: You should install the SSL-certificate on the server, not in your Keystore.

Comment: @JanP yes, but the Problem is, that the request gets canceled before a connection to the server is made. And when I build as a debug version it works fine.

Comment: @Eric I will check that

Comment: I faced with the same in my app. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32030346)