# ionic framework + cordova. WebSocket is not working in the android release version, but the debug version works correctly

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, websocket, release

**With this logs:**

WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxxxxx.net/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled"

"TransportWebSocket.errorHandler - Error {}"

"TransportWebSocket.closeHandler - Error {"code":1006,"text":""}"

**Please help with this problem.**

```
sp.external.TransportWebSocket = function () {
        var self = this;
        var socket = null;
        var isOpen = false;
        var listSendMsg = [];

        this.openHandler = null;
        this.closeHandler = null;
        this.messageHandler = null;
        this.errorHandler = null;
        this.serverURL = '';

        this.send = function (_data, _highPrioritetFlag) {
            utils.logger.debug('TransportWebSocket', 'send', 'Open status:' + isOpen);

            _highPrioritetFlag = _highPrioritetFlag || false;

            if (isOpen) {
                if (_data && typeof _data === 'object') {
                    try {
                        socket.send(JSON.stringify(_data));
                    }
                    catch (error) {
                        throw new Error('Invalid JSON stringify');
                    }
                }
                else {
                    throw new Error('The data sent must be an object');
                }
            }
            else {
                if (_highPrioritetFlag) {
                    listSendMsg.unshift(_data);
                }
                else {
                    listSendMsg.push(_data);
                }

                openSocket();
            }
        };

        this.reopen = function () {
            utils.logger.debug('TransportWebSocket', 'reopen');
            openSocket();
        };

        this.close = function (_code) {
            utils.logger.debug('TransportWebSocket', 'close');
            socket.close(_code);
        };

        function procListMsg() {
            utils.logger.debug('TransportWebSocket', 'procListMsg', 'Processing buffer messages, items:' + listSendMsg.length);
            if (listSendMsg.length > 0) {
                self.send(listSendMsg.shift());
                setTimeout(procListMsg, 20);
            }
        }

        function openHandler() {
            utils.logger.debug('TransportWebSocket', 'openHandler', 'WebSocket.readyState:' + socket.readyState);
            if (socket.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
                isOpen = true;

                procListMsg();

                if (self.openHandler) {
                    self.openHandler();
                }
            }
        }

        function closeHandler(error) {
            utils.logger.debug('TransportWebSocket', 'closeHandler', 'Error', {code: error.code, text: error.reason});
            isOpen = false;

            if (socket.readyState === WebSocket.CLOSED) {

                if (self.closeHandler) {
                    self.closeHandler(error);
                }
            }
        }

        function errorHandler(error) {
            utils.logger.debug('TransportWebSocket', 'errorHandler', 'Error', {code: error.code, text: error.reason});
            isOpen = false;

            if (self.errorHandler) {
                self.errorHandler(error);
            }
        }

        function messageHandler(e) {
            var msg = null;

            if (self.messageHandler) {
                try {
                    msg = JSON.parse(e.data);
                }
                catch (error) {
                    throw new Error('Invalid JSON format in response: ' + e.data);
                }

                self.messageHandler(msg);
            }
        }

        function openSocket() {
            utils.logger.debug('TransportWebSocket', 'openSocket', 'Opening');
            socket = new WebSocket(self.serverURL);
            socket.onopen = openHandler;
            socket.onclose = closeHandler;
            socket.onmessage = messageHandler;
            socket.onerror = errorHandler;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: I added module's code

Comment: Do you have network permissions?

Comment: Yes, I have this string in AndroidManifest.xml <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have solved this issue, but for people encountering the same trouble and who find this thread, you may check this [cordova "release" behaves differently to "debug" regarding SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32021743/cordova-release-behaves-differently-to-debug-regarding-ssl)

In short, modify the file that is making the behavior different between debug and release:
`platforms/android/CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova/engine/SystemWebViewClient.java`

Comment out the content of the method `onReceivedSslError` and replace it with

```
handler.proceed();
return;
```